# How to run a tSQL query on SQL Server from Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have been tasked with creating a spreadsheet to present certain data from a long-established SQL Server database. I have, previously, written a tSQL query that returns exactly the data needed.

What I need to know is how (and whether) I can query SQL Server, from within Excel, using my ready-written tSQL query. For preference taking values from spreadsheet cells to fill SQL variables as well.

I've been casting around in Power Query, looking for a way to do this, but it seems to want entirely different syntax. I am not familiar with that syntax and don't have time to learn it. I've also tried searching online for a solution, or even a discussion of what I want to do and come up empty.

Comment: Data -> Get Data -> From Database -> SQL Server menu options and then "Advanced" to paste in your static query to start with. That still leaves the task of integrating the dynamic values from the spreadsheet though

Comment: @MartinSmith that helps, thank you. Can I include data from spreadsheet cells?

Comment: Definitely possible. Just right click the cells and choose "Get data from table/range" to see the syntax used in Power Query. I suspect trying to combine them may be a bit tricky though to get around the cross data source restrictions